# OKD Build process cannot resolve host

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools, okd

I cannot build pods in OKD as Github cannot be resolved and the build fails.

The error:

```
Cloning "https://github.com/MeMyselfI/okd-hello-world " ...
error: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/MeMyselfI/okd-hello-world/': Could not resolve host: github.com; Unknown error
```

How OKD is started:

```
sudo oc cluster up --routing-suffix=192.168.2.20.xip.io --public-hostname=192.168.2.20
```

OC client version:

```
me@server:~$ sudo oc version
oc v3.11.0+0cbc58b
kubernetes v1.11.0+d4cacc0
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO
```

`ping` from SSH prompt:

```
me@server:~$ ping github.com
PING github.com (192.30.253.113) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lb-192-30-253-113-iad.github.com (192.30.253.113): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=33.4 ms
64 bytes from lb-192-30-253-113-iad.github.com (192.30.253.113): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=34.0 ms
```

`ping` from local, manually launched, Docker container:

```
me@server:~$ sudo docker exec -it hwnodemongo_web_1 /bin/bash
root@7c2db2faacf7:/usr/src/app# ping github.com
PING github.com (192.30.253.112) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lb-192-30-253-112-iad.github.com (192.30.253.112): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=28.3 ms
64 bytes from lb-192-30-253-112-iad.github.com (192.30.253.112): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=27.4 ms
```

Output of `resolv.conf`

```
me@server:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

`dnsmasq` is running:

```
dnsmasq   1479  0.0  0.0  51580   376 ?        S    12:07   0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -x /run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid -u dnsmasq -7 /etc/dnsmasq.d,.dpkg-dist,.dpkg-old,.dpkg-new --local-service --trust-anchor=.,19036,8,2,49aac11d7b6f6446702e54a1607371607a1a41855200fd2ce1cdde32f24e8fb5 --trust-anchor=.,20326,8,2,e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409bbc683457104237c7f8ec8d
```

`dig` from SSH:

```
me@server.com:~$ dig github.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.5-Ubuntu <<>> github.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 20999
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;github.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
github.com.             59      IN      A       192.30.253.113
github.com.             59      IN      A       192.30.253.112

;; Query time: 46 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Fri Apr 05 13:23:47 ADT 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 71
```

**Update:**

I redid the install on another machine. I used `oc cluster up` (without any other parameters) and got the same results (by accessing `localhost:8443/console`).